# Fetching basic information (id, first_name) from Facebook by using Social Framework - source code and screenshots attached

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, social-framework

For what would be a word game later I am trying to fetch very basic information about a player by using Social framework:

- id
- first_name
- gender
- location

(i.e. nothing sensitive like `email` and I don't use Facebook iOS SDK).

So in Xcode 5.0.2 I create a blank single view app for iPhone and add `Social.framework` to the *Build phases* tab.

Then I add the following code to the [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyFacebook/MyFacebook):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>

#define FB_APP_ID @"432298283565593"
//#define FB_APP_ID @"262571703638"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) ACAccountStore *accountStore;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Facebook is available: %d", [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]);

    [self getMyDetails];
}

- (void) getMyDetails {
    if (!_accountStore) {
        _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    }

    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [_accountStore
                                        accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: FB_APP_ID,
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"basic_info"]};

    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                           options:options
                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
        if (granted) {
            NSLog(@"Basic access granted");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Basic access denied %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

And create [a new Facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/432298283565593/) for which I specify `de.afarber.MyFacebook` as the iOS *Bundle ID*:

[image]

Finally at Apple iTunes Connect I create a new App ID and then a new app (with a dummy icon and even 2 iPhone screenshots attached):

[image]

[image]

My Xcode *Info* tab and the rest of the source code are unchanged:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I have updated the source code as suggested by helpful comments, thank you.

Also, I have [another Facebook game](https://facebook.com/appcenter/video-preferans), which works well (since 1-2 years) for an Adobe AIR desktop and mobile apps (but now I try to learn native iOS programming) and I have tried its id `262571703638` without success.

And I have added `FacebookAppID` to `MyFacebook-Info.plist` as suggested by Mohit10 (it seems to me that it is needed for Facebook SDK only, while I try to use Social Framework - but it can't hurt...)

Now I get the debugger output:

```
2013-12-31 11:08:07.584 MyFacebook[3009:70b] Facebook is available: 1
2013-12-31 11:08:07.964 MyFacebook[3009:3903] Basic access granted
```

I just need to figure out, how to fetch the id, first_name, gender, location now (and if `basic_info` is really needed for that)...

Comment: Not sure if it's entirely related to the error you're seeing, but the permissions you're requesting (id, first_name, gender, location) are not actually valid FB permissions. For a list of valid permissions, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/

Comment: I've taken the same strings as in the PHP version (of my other app), so I wonder what strings do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what your other app does, all I know is that "id" and "first_name" are not valid facebook permissions, and should not be passed to ACFacebookPermissionsKey.  Things like "basic_info", "user_birthday" are permissions. The parameters you're setting look like the fields you want when you actually make a user request (i.e. &fields=id,gender,first_name,location).

Comment: You're correct and maybe I should just try a `SLRequest` w/o asking for permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

- `ACAccountStore *accountStore` is going out of scope, it should be an instance variable.
- You don't need the `ACFacebookAudienceKey`, that's for publishing.
- You don't need the `ACFacebookPermissionsKey` as the properties you want are [available by default](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/)

With these fixes your code still doesn't work for me, although it does work for my App ID. I get the the following error:

```
"The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid application 432298283565593" UserInfo=0x1d5ab670 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid application 432298283565593}
```

Looks like there's something wrong with your app's Facebook configuration.

The only difference I can see is that my app is sandboxed and I'm logged in using my developer account. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the source code as (I think) you suggest... and have also tried another (already working) Facebook Id app - but the error is still the same: `Basic access denied (null)`. I will set a bounty of 500 tomorrow on my question

Comment: Did you update the BundleID to match the working Facebook app ID? Deleting the app and doing a clean rebuild before doing this doesn't hurt either, as Xcode can get confused.

Answer (score 3):

With the helpful comments (thank you) I've finally been able to fetch some information with the following code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>

#define FB_APP_ID @"432298283565593"
//#define FB_APP_ID @"262571703638"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) ACAccount *facebookAccount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ACAccountType *facebookAccountType;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ACAccountStore *accountStore;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (NO == [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        [self showAlert:@"There are no Facebook accounts configured. Please add or create a Facebook account in Settings."];
        return;
    }

    [self getMyDetails];
}

- (void) getMyDetails {
    if (! _accountStore) {
        _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    }

    if (! _facebookAccountType) {
        _facebookAccountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    }

    NSDictionary *options = @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey: FB_APP_ID };

    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType: _facebookAccountType
                                           options: options
                                        completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:_facebookAccountType];
            _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

            SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                              URL:url
                                                       parameters:nil];
            request.account = _facebookAccount;

            [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                     error:nil];
                NSLog(@"id: %@", responseDictionary[@"id"]);
                NSLog(@"first_name: %@", responseDictionary[@"first_name"]);
                NSLog(@"last_name: %@", responseDictionary[@"last_name"]);
                NSLog(@"gender: %@", responseDictionary[@"gender"]);
                NSLog(@"city: %@", responseDictionary[@"location"][@"name"]);
            }];
        } else {
            [self showAlert:@"Facebook access for this app has been denied. Please edit Facebook permissions in Settings."];
        }
    }];
}

- (void) showAlert:(NSString*) msg {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"WARNING"
                                  message:msg
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    });
}

@end
```

This prints my data:

```
id: 597287941
first_name: Alexander
last_name: Farber
gender: male
city: Bochum, Germany
```

If you have any improvement suggestions, you're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not made any changes in your .plist file, you need to add your FacebookAppID in your .plist file. From that I think it will be helpful to you get the user details and you will be able to integrate it from your settings also.[image]

Comment: Thank you, but isn't `FacebookAppID` for Facebook iOS SDK (for the `FBSession`)? While I'm trying to use Apple Social Framework...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple

in viewDidLoad() use:

```
accountStore= [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
facebookAccountType= [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary *options= @{
ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceEveryone,
ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"<YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID>",
ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"public_profile"]

                          };


[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted) {
        NSLog(@"Permission has been granted to the app");
        NSArray *accounts= [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
        facebookAccount= [accounts firstObject];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(facebookProfile) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Permission denied to the app");
    }
}];
```

/////And the function
   -(void)facebookProfile{

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
```

//////Notice the params you need are added as dictionary
   ///Refer below for complete list
   ////https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

```
NSDictionary *param=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name",@"fields", nil];

SLRequest *profileInfoRequest= [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:param];
profileInfoRequest.account= facebookAccount;


[profileInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Facebook status code is : %ld", (long)[urlResponse statusCode]);

    if ([urlResponse statusCode]==200) {

        NSDictionary *dictionaryData= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];



    } else {

    }
}];


}
```