# Get Facebook info using Social Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently i have integrated Facebook SDK into my app. and it works fine.

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");

             //Retriving FB Info
             NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
             [parameters setValue:@"id,name,email" forKey:@"fields"];

             [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
              startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                           id result, NSError *error) {

                  NSLog(@"FB INFO %@",result);


              }];

         }
     }];
```

but then i heard using social framework, without redirecting i can get the user details as well. but i havent found any relevant document regarding that. i have found some [tutorials](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/integrating-social-media-in-your-apps/) but only explaining how to make a post to facebook.

How to get Facebook name and email address from social framework?

Comment: Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829767/fetching-basic-information-id-first-name-from-facebook-by-using-social-framew)

Comment: Hope this helps you : - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27532079/3515115